# Изменить метки маршрута (не мультимаршрута) на свои

Tags: api, yandex-maps-api, карты

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать собственный макет меток, чтобы можно было небольшой шаблон html и текст в несколько строк делать?

```
route.getPaths().options.set({
balloonContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('{{ properties.humanJamsTime }}'),
    // Можно выставить настройки графики маршруту.
    strokeColor: color,
    strokeWidth: 3,
    opacity: .9
});

var points = route.getWayPoints();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример задания собственного макета метки
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape . 
Для того чтобы задать макет меткам маршрута нужно написать так :

```
var points = route.getWayPoints();
points.options.set({
        iconLayout: squareLayout,
        // Описываем фигуру активной области "Прямоугольник".
        iconShape: {
            type: 'Rectangle',
            // Прямоугольник описывается в виде двух точек - верхней левой и нижней правой.
            coordinates: [
                [-25, -25], [25, 25]
            ]
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dhmpawy/

Comment: Большое спасибо. А как добавить туда сразу контет, не в баллун всплывающий а прям туда? iconContent?

Comment: В макет можно передавать используемое поле так {{properties.iconContent}} и пример https://jsfiddle.net/hndgfv3s/

Comment: Большое спасибо. А еще вопрос, последний. Как сделать чтобы контент расширял блок метки? Стилями css?

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо

Comment: А можно активную область метки сделать чтобы она была по ширине и высоте шаблона ???

Comment: вот пример как это делается для балуна https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan ровно также это делается и для метки

Comment: Спасибо, супер, разобрался.
https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/4c2664b2-9e2b-4d17-a209-4ba05ccb2e50.png
Ставлю некий html код в iconContent, а он выводит теги.

Comment: попробуйте искать ответы в документации https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Template-docpage/ она огненная, и там всё есть) И в примерах тоже показаны многие возможности https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/cluster_balloon_carousel